# Can someone explain this RegEx behaviour?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I experience a strange behaviour when working with RegEx.

```
dataString = "#Name #Location New York #Rating"
string[] rawValues = Regex.Split(dataString.Trim(), "(^|\\s)+#\\w+");
```

The pattern matches: `"#Name", " #Location", " #Rating"` (which is what I intend to match).
The split returns: `["", "", "", " ", "New York", " ", ""]`

Question #1: The cunfusion starts already here. Why are there empty strings at positions `0,1,2`? Two for the matches and one because it was at the first position of the string?

But this was not the strange part.

```
string[] rawValues = Regex.Split(dataString.Trim(), "(\\s|^)+#(\\w*[A-Za-z_]+\\w*)");
```

The pattern matches: `"#Name", " #Location", " #Rating"` (the same as before).
But the split returns: `["", "", "Name", "", " ", "Location"," New York", " ", "Rating",""]`

Question #2: A pattern which leads to the exact same match, results in a totally different split output. How is this possible??

Comment: First off, a general recommendation: in C# use verbatim strings for regexes, to avoid double backslashes. E.g.: `@"(\s|^)+#(\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)"`

Comment: thx, I didn't know that. I'm not using C# very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is this sentence from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx):

> If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array.

You you shouldn't use capturing groups in `Split` if you really just want to split the string at matches. You can avoid capturing groups, by using `(?:...)` in place of every `(...)` you have.

Plus, as you correctly assumed. The first and last `""` originate from the fact that the string starts and ends with a match (so the empty string before and after these matches will be reported in the split).

Here is a regular expression that is better suited for you purposes:

```
@"(?:^|\s+)#\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*"
```

Note that having the `+` outside of your first subpattern was also unnecessary and led to awkward side effects. Firstly it allowed the group to capture multiple times (which is why you got two addition `""`, `""`: one for `^` and one for `\s`). Secondly, there is no need to repeat `^` after the first space character has been matched, so it is enough to repeat only the space character. Also, there is no need to group the word after `#` at all.

However, if all you want is to match something like `#name` when it is at the start of the string or preceded by a space (i.e. **not* preceded by a **non-space** character), why include possible spaces in the match at all. A negative lookbehind gives you a nice way out:

```
@"(?<!\S)#\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*"
```

This does exactly what described above. The `(?<!\S)` matches if there is no non-space character left to it (without including a space-character in the match if there is one). That covers both cases without alternation, **and** you don't need to `Trim` your key names.

Comment: Wow, this explains a lot:) Regarding the regex pattern itself. I changed it to `@"(?:^|\s+)#(?:\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*)"`. Basically I need to match #<name> at the beginning of a string or after a white character within the string. The constraints for <name> are: `[A-Za-z]` allowed, `_` allowed (at least one of these two is mandatory), `\d` allowed. It seems to work so far but maybe this can be achieved easier...

Comment: @rob then what do you need `Split` for at all?

Comment: @m well, it's user input in the form of `#key1 value vablue value #key2 some more value #name_of_key and so on` and I need to match the keys first and get the according values after :)

Comment: @rob I edited my answer to provide you with a nicer regex for both cases

Answer (score 0):

Because the regular expression on which you are splitting matches 1 or more whitespace followed by a hash ('#') followed by 1 or more word characters.

Anything that matches that doesn't get included in the results.

There's two ways you can do this:

1. Split on what is not wanted and filter the results.
2. Actively search for only what is wanted.

Here's some code with both of the above options:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    string   sourceText = "#Name #Location New York #Rating" ;

    // option 1: split on whitespace and then toss whatever isn't wanted
    string[] hashTokens1 = sourceText.Split().Where( x => x.StartsWith("#") ).ToArray() ;

    // option 2: actively search for what is desired
    string[] hashTokens2 = ParseSourceData( sourceText ).ToArray() ;

    return ;

}

private static readonly Regex hashTokenPattern = new Regex( @"#\w+");
private static IEnumerable<string> ParseSourceData( string s )
{
    for ( Match m = hashTokenPattern.Match( s ) ; m.Success ; m = m.NextMatch() )
    {
        yield return m.Value ;
    }
}
```

Myself, I'd use the 2nd option as it better states the case for what you're trying to accomplish. A good general rule is to prefer positive assertions or tests over negative.

You can also write the 2nd option as a "one-liner, thus:

```
// option 2: actively search for what is desired
Regex hashTokenPattern = new Regex( @"#\w+");
string[] hashTokens2 = hashTokenPattern.Matches(sourceText).Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray();
```